# Java Bank Account Synchronization example. Fail to see how solution works

Tags: java, synchronization, account, bank

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D01ja.png

So, I'm reading a pdf about synchronization that shows the above example problem. A bit later, the following is presented, presumably as a solution:

```
class Account
{
  private double balance;
  public Account(double initialDeposit) {
    balance = initialDeposit;
  }
  public synchronized double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }
  public synchronized void setBalance(double newBalance) {
    balance = newBalance;
  }
  public synchronized void deposit (double amt) {
   //essentially still multiple steps when in bytecode!
   balance += amt;
  }
```

I don't understand how this solves the problem. Maybe that's not what was intended, but it seems implied. I'm looking for some confirmation on whether it does or doesn't. 
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of using the synchronized keyword is that only one thread can access the method at a time and the schema on your image becomes impossible.

But as discussed below, the presence of the setBalance method makes it possible to misuse the class and obtain an undesired output.

Comment: Thread one gets the lock, grabs the balance. Thread two gets the lock, grabs the balance.

Comment: I still don't understand. If the lock is given up between calling getBalance() and setBalance(), anything can still happen during that gap.

Comment: You are supposed to use the deposit method. If you use getBalance, do your math and then use setBalance, it obviously defeats the purpose of synchronized which was to make sure that a deposit is an atomic action.

Comment: I agree that it is not a very good example - there should not be a setBalance method.

Comment: Very good. That was my main issue. I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some subtle cleverness. Thank you.

Comment: Not sure what you are reading, but Java Concurrency in Practice is an excellent and understandable reference that I would recommend.

Answer (score 3):

The [`synchronized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html) keyword is making sure two threads cannot get into a synchronized block [on the same object] concurrently.

In your case, the 3 methods cannot be invoked on the same objects concurrently because each is holding a lock on `this` when invoked.

So, nevertheless `balance += amt;` is not atomic - it is synchronized, and thus it is not possible that the state will change during the the evaluation of this statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be surprised if the PDF is proposing that as the final solution as it completely fails to solve the problem shown your image!
Maybe it's showing you a naive attempt to solve the problem, by spraying synchronized keywords around a bit?

I would keep reading your PDF - And post your findings!

Comment: That would make sense indeed!

Comment: Yes saw your other comments, not the best example if that's all there is!

Comment: The class is thread safe.
• If we have an object acc of Account, thread t1 and t2.
When t1 is calling acc.deposit(500); t2 cannot start
executing acc.deposit(1000) until t1 is done with the
method.
• The methods setBalance() and getBalance() are also
synched, since balance may change during reading,
writing if not synchronized.

Comment: ^^^ That's what else was written about the example. I admittedly overlooked the suggestion to use deposit, but the availability of the setBalance() method still makes the class pretty useless I think.

Comment: Poor example really , not surprised you found it confusing. Sounds like you have a good handle on what's going on. There would need to be some sort of locking introduced to fix the original example in your image eg ReentrantReadWriteLock